# What is "Winter is Coming" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm an avid follower of the TV-show "Game of Thrones", and wonder what a Latin translation of the Stark's families motto — "Winter is Coming" — would be?

It's used in the form of a warning, that there are dark and difficult days ahead.  Should perhaps also add that in the GoT-universe, a winter lasts for years (decades)...

http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Stark

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried translating the phrase yourself? You might want to consult [this guide](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/143/79) for asking translation questions. Online dictionaries listed in [our dictionary question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) might also be useful.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  Tried without much success.  Admittedly I tried using a book rather than the net, but what stomped me were the subtleties of Latin - is "Winter is Coming" here a general observation, an exclamation, a warning, more of a command...?  As I understand it, suffixes are real important in Latin (jfr. Monty Pythons: Life of Brian famous discussion about "Romans Go Home!")

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbI-fDzUJXI   (Sort of scared me... ;-)

Comment: *Immineo* can mean "to be near at hand, to impend, to threaten by nearness, to be imminent".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Caesar (B. Gall., iii, 27) simply uses *subest* “be close at hand, be near”: *...quod hiems suberat...*

Thus, *hiems subest*.

Comment: I like this suggestion. The *Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary* also suggests *instat* and *appetit*, which (for me) are slightly more evocative.

Comment: Add a touch of the medieval with "hiemps" for Winter.

Comment: @brianpck I think you should offer these as an answer. In particular *instat* evokes the threat that always underlies that sentence in *Solium Ludus*.

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised *appropinquo* (sometimes spelled *adpropinquo*) hasn't been mentioned yet. Caesar (*Bellum Civile* 3.9) also uses this one, and to my ears, it better fits what is being said in the show.

> jamque hiems adpropinquabat
>
> At that point winter was approaching...

I can envision Romans, worried about the coming winter, saying "Hiems appropinquat."

Visually, if you imagine winter to be a person, you could see that person approaching you, but they're not yet there. Meanwhile, *subesse* means more "at hand," where that person is standing near you but hasn't yet begun to speak; perhaps that person is just nearby.

Similarly, *nox appropinquat* would mean late afternoon, while *nox subest* would mean twilight: the sun has just set, but it's still somewhat light out.

This makes sense if we look at a few parallel passages. Livy (3.34) and Cicero both talk about the time relative to the day of the *comitia*.

> A rumour was then spread that two tables were wanting; on the addition of which a body, as it were, of the whole Roman law might be completed. The expectation of this, as the day of election approached, created a desire to appoint decemvirs again.
>
> volgatur deinde rumor duas deesse tabulas quibus adiectis absolvi posse velut corpus omnis Romani iuris. ea exspectatio, cum **dies comitiorum adpropinquaret**, desiderium decemviros iterum creandi fecit.

The election was fast approaching, but it had not yet *arrived*. Meanwhile, Cicero's parallel (*Pro Milone* 42) using *subesse* shows a more immediate closeness with less movement.

> especially, O judges, when the day of contest for the greatest distinction of the state, and the day of the comitia, was at hand.
>
> praesertim, iudices, cum honoris amplissimi contentio et dies comitiorum subesset.

The event being described as occurring when the *comitia* were being called together, not days before, as they were in the Livy passage. Though voting hadn't taken place it, the nearness of it was already established and not coming into nearness. It was *at hand*.

This makes sense even etymologically. The root implies non-movement: *esse* is simply a form of "to be." When Caesar (BG 1.25) expressed the relationship of a town to a mountain, he used *subesse*:

> Tandem vulneribus defessi et pedem referre et, quod mons suberit circiter mille passuum spatio, eo se recipere coeperunt.
>
> At length, worn out with wounds, they began to give way, and, as there was in the neighborhood a mountain about a mile off, to betake themselves thither.

The mountain isn't moving closer to them, but rather is described as close (only a mile off). If anyone were to be moving, it would be the soldiers, and the word to use here (of the two) would have been *approprinquare*.

We can again visualize the way the word works by comparing it to other *esse* words. Below I put TU et EGO together to show the relationship of the verbs:

```
1. TUEGO (adesse)
2. TU  EGO (subesse)
3. TU
     EGO (subesse)
4. TU                               EGO (abesse)
```

To put all this back into winter, bearing in mind that language can be imprecise, and bearing in mind that descriptions can be exaggerated (so I'm not saying necessarily that *hiems subest* is wrong!), but were I to hear *hiems subest*, I would imagine December already, on the eve of winter, whereas I would use *hiems appropinquat* to describe the action of winter approaching, though it still be fall. This could be late October when the chilly north wind blows or November when frost begins to appear. In either case, signs are present that winter is approaching, but not yet here.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I, too, wonder why *appropinquare* had not been suggested. Thanks for bringing it up and elaborating on nuance and classical precedent!

Comment: Thank you, that verb did not come into my mind when I remembered the *subest* paradigm. To me *appropinquo* sounds more immediate and more effectful if not threatening than rather stative *subest*

Comment: @kkm It does have a menacing feel to it, doesn't it? "Death approaches" v. "death is near" sort of distinction, it seems.

Comment: @cmw: Exactly! *Menacing* was the word I was in a loss for!

Comment: [This answer has been nominated as one of the best answers of the first quarter of 2017.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/269/79)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I believe to answer your first question the reason is because too often in a language people will not actually translate meaning, but words. But words cannot ever be translated in isolation, as they lack meaning without context. It's the difference between connotation and denotation. To make matters worse, often people will look for what's possible, rather than what's likely, as if no usage could be idiomatic or awkward.

Comment: @cmw Indeed. If only we found a way to communicate that to all new users about to ask their first translation question... The way I've described translation to many is that you read a story in one language, understand it, and then retell it in another. That usually brings about the right mindset. [Near-synonyms that technically work are often weird or unsettling.](https://xkcd.com/2352/)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That's a great XKCD, and how very apropos that it was released shortly before I found this question again!

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is: *Hiems venit* (*hiems* is winter, *venit* is comes).

[*Hiems*:](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:hiems) Winter

[*Venire*:](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb:venire) To come/go

Comment: Welcome to the site! *Hiems venit* is indeed a good translation. It should be noted that it means more "winter comes" than "winter is coming". I am not sure if this tone is a problem.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you added some more information, like the dictionary entries for the words.

Comment: Intuitively, the reverse order *Venit hiems* sounds more natural to my ears, though I can't quite explain why. (Btw *venire* is not "to go", but only "to come".)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta There is technically no difference between the two when going from English to Latin. You could do _hiems est veniens_, but that is more using _venio_ as an adjective to describe winter, and doesn't truly mean the same thing deep down.

Comment: @SamK, *hiems est veniens* is not good, but *hiems est ventura* is more idiomatic Latin. I would suggest using it if one wants to make the distinction between "comes" and "is coming" in Latin. If there's no need for the distinction, *venit* is good. It's just a matter of getting the tone right.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It's always about the tone... :)

Answer (score 6):

> *Hiemis imminet adventus.*

This construction gets at the foreboding idea of the "winter is
coming" phrase used in "Game of Thrones". Like the original English, it has three words. As a saying, it gets your attention with its stylish emphasis on the verb, *imminet*, framed by *hiemis* and *adventus*.  I like the other suggestions too, but wanted to add this for your consideration.

As far as I know, this is not a classical construction. I
adapted it from a sentence in a commentary on Vergil's Aeneid written by [Maurus Servius Honoratus](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Servius), a grammarian of the 4th century in Rome.  ([accessed on the Perseus Digital Library](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0053%3Abook%3D3%3Acommline%3D276)). See reference below.

> *Vel quia **hiemis imminebat adventus.***
>
> to explain *fessi* --Book 3, line 276 of The Aeneid:
>
> *Hunc petimus fessi et parvae succedimus urbi.*

Maurus Servius Honoratus. In Vergilii carmina comentarii. Servii Grammatici qui feruntur in Vergilii carmina commentarii; recensuerunt Georgius Thilo et Hermannus Hagen. Georgius Thilo. Leipzig. B. G. Teubner. 1881.

Comment: I like this suggestion I also think you're selling yourself short by saying "this is not a classical construction": of course it is! Just because no author has put certain words together doesn't mean it's dubious--that would more apply to an unattested grammatical form or a neologism.